# Get count of rows based if column exists in two different tables

Tags: wpdb, sql

I have two custom tables which both contain a column called `reference`.

`wp_invites`

| id | lead_name | reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | fRgOeRkFeHIm |
| 2 | Alex | WtRA7T7NFdYW |
| 3 | Jason | IGr0ZhaCbojD |

`wp_rsvp`

| id | accepted | reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | fRgOeRkFeHIm |
| 2 | yes | WtRA7T7NFdYW |

I'm now trying to get a `count` to see how many users are yet to respond to an RSVP. The way I'm determining this is by checking if there `reference` exists in the `wp_rsvp` table.

For example, considering the above tables, yet to respond would be `1`, as Jason's reference doesn't exist in the `wp_rsvp` table.

If I'm on the right lines, I believe I need a `UNION ALL` clause? However, I'm unsure on how I can link the two tables? i.e.

`Select all from wp_rsvp where reference exists in wp_invites and return count`

It is this `WHERE` clause that is confusing me as it's not a value known beforehand?

Workings so far:

```
global $wpdb;
$rsvp_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'rsvp';
$invites_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'invites';
    
$yet_to_respond = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $rsvp_table, $invites_table  WHERE reference='" . . "'");    
echo $yet_to_respond;
```

Comment: Have you looked into SQL JOINS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a join in your mysql query.

Something like this might get you closer...

```
global $wpdb;
$rsvp_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'rsvp';
$invites_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'invites';

$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
FROM $invites_table i1 
JOIN $rsvp_table r1 ON (r1.reference = i1.reference)';

$yet_to_respond = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

echo $yet_to_respond->count;
```